# Transferring an interactive Python Bokeh plot into Shiny

Tags: r, python-3.x, shiny, bokeh

I created some visualizations using Bokeh in Python. Would it be possible to export them into R shiny?

*Images/ Plots haven't been added as this is a generic question and doesn't warrant a minimally reproducible example.

Comment: Interesting! When ppl don't know the answer they downvote it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [rbokeh](https://hafen.github.io/rbokeh/articles/rbokeh.html) library (after adapting the data to R syntax), and use the `renderRbokeh()` function and `rbokehOutput()` [widget](https://rdrr.io/cran/rbokeh/man/rbokehOutput.html).